# Broken packages when trying to install VLC on Debian Sid

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player, apt, debian-stretch

After upgrading the whole system to Sid, I had some troubles with NVidia drivers, which I had to reinstall. But I noticed that some VLC dependencies got lost alongside the NVidia uninstall process. And sure enought, VLC was not there anymore. I can't install VLC from Sid, from Stable and from Videolan's own PPA.

Now, every time I try to reinstall VLC, I get this output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-l10n (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 3.0.0~rc4-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And also:

```
$ sudo apt install vlc=2.2.7-1~deb9u1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-bin (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but 3.0.0~rc4-2 is to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but 3.0.0~rc4-2 is to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but 3.0.0~rc4-2 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 2.2.7-1~deb9u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install one by one recursively, it comes to a point where a specific package version can't be found anywhere.

Currently my cache policy is like this:

```
vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.0~rc4-2
  Version table:
     3.0.0~rc4-2 500
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.7-1~deb9u1 500
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

This is my `sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 9.3.0 xfce 2017-12-09T13:26]/ sid main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main non-free contrib

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Also on `sources.list.d`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial main
```

And if I try to install the PPA version:

```
$ sudo apt install vlc=2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
       Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I also tried:

```
$ sudo apt install vlc-nox=2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc-nox : Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable or
                    libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libavformat-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libchromaprint0 (>= 0.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable
           Depends: liblivemedia50 but it is not installable
           Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libpostproc-ffmpeg53 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not installable
           Depends: libsidplay2v5 but it is not installable
           Depends: libswscale-ffmpeg3 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not installable
           Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libx265-79 (>= 1.9) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I sure did try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

Many, many times.

Comment: Check your software sources. If you added a repo for VLC then chances are it has no packages for Sid.

Comment: I tried deselecting other sources, still to no avail.

Comment: Oh thanks for the downvote without any explanation, that's sure helpful.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I understand why someone did. And also your supposed answer is really poor and doesn't help others / it's below standards in the site. That I downvote confidently.

Comment: My answer is enough for someone who doesn't need his hand held the whole process. But you can downvote all you want, instead of actually contributing, if that makes you feel better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-with-held-broken-packages-error)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by uninstalling NVidia drivers completely, installing VLC and then reinstalling NVidia. Not sure how those two things are related.